# Setting up MySQL SSL connections

Tags: mysql, ssl, amazon-ec2

My task is to make all local and remote connections to MySQL encrypted and all clients must be verified by client SSL certificates.

But I can't even connect to MySQL from shell and always getting 'Access denied for user `ssluser@localhost`...)'

---

Platform:

- Amazon EC2 micro with Amazon Linux AMI (all updates installed)
- MySQL 5.7.7

I have created the self-signed certificate in accordance with [this instruction](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/creating-ssl-files-using-openssl.html)

```
# Create CA certificate 
# -----------
# CN = localdomain.com

$ openssl genrsa 2048 > ca-key.pem
$ openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -days 3600 -key ca-key.pem -out ca.pem


# Create server certificate, remove passphrase, and sign it
# server-cert.pem = public key, server-key.pem = private key
# ----------- 
# CN = cn1.localdomain.com

$ openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -days 3600 -nodes -keyout server-key.pem -out server-req.pem
$ openssl rsa -in server-key.pem -out server-key.pem
$ openssl x509 -req -in server-req.pem -days 3600 -CA ca.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem -set_serial 01 -out server-cert.pem


# Create client certificate, remove passphrase, and sign it
# client-cert.pem = public key, client-key.pem = private key
# ----------- 
# CN = cn2.localdomain.com

$ openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -days 3600 -nodes -keyout client-key.pem -out client-req.pem
$ openssl rsa -in client-key.pem -out client-key.pem
$ openssl x509 -req -in client-req.pem -days 3600 -CA ca.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem -set_serial 01 -out client-cert.pem
```

I have created the MySQL DB user for testing

```
CREATE USER 'ssl-user'@'%' identified by '123';
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'ssluser'@'%' identified by '123' REQUIRE X509;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Edited my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
ssl-ca=/etc/pki/mysql_ssl/ca.pem
ssl-cert=/etc/pki/mysql_ssl/server-cert.pem
ssl-key=/etc/pki/mysql_ssl/server-key.pem

[client]
ssl-cert=/etc/pki/mysql_ssl/client-cert.pem
ssl-key=/etc/pki/mysql_ssl/client-key.pem
```

and restarted mysqld...

---

Than I am trying to connect from shell

```
mysql -ussluser -p123123123 --ssl-cert=/etc/pki/mysql_ssl/client-cert.pem --ssl-key=/etc/pki/mysql_ssl/client-key.pem
```

And always get 'Access denied for `ssluser@localhost` (using password: YES).

I also tried to use our purchased WildCard Comodo Certificates to only encrypt the connection (but not verify the client) with no success.

I am a bit confused because I know a lot of people actually do MySQL SSL, but I am still can't get it working.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is solved.

- I switched back to MySQL 5.6
- Re-created CA, server and client certificates with [this detailed instruction](http://oracle-base.com/articles/mysql/mysql-configure-ssl-connections.php#server-configuration)
- Added to my.cnf the client SSL section

  ```
  [client]
  ssl-ca=/etc/pki/mysql_ssl/ca-cert.pem
  ssl-cert=/etc/pki/mysql_ssl/client-cert.pem
  ssl-key=/etc/pki/mysql_ssl/сlient-key.pem
  ```
- Created new mysql user

  ```
  CREATE USER 'x509test'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyPassword1';
  GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'x509test'@'%' REQUIRE X509;
  FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
  ```

---

And finally I am able to connect

```
$ mysql --user=x509test --password --ssl-ca=/etc/pki/mysql_ssl/ca-cert.pem --ssl-cert=/etc/pki/mysql_ssl/client-cert.pem --ssl-key=/etc/pki/mysql_ssl/client-key.pem
```